# Cancelling NSThread that runs C++ code

Tags: cocoa, nsthread, objective-c++

My NSThread's selector is a wrapper for a potentially long-running C++ method.  I want the thread to respond to the `- cancel` message, which requires checking in with the NSThread  object itself and asking if it `isCancelled`.
How can my C++ code send messages to the NSThread it's running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way as any in Objective C or pure C code, assuming you're using Objective C++ code (the .mm extension, by default, compiles as Objective C++). Then just use `[[NSThread   currentThread] isCancelled]` inside your C++ code to check the thread cancellation status.

The restrictions on the interface between Objective C and C++ given by Objective C++ are outlined rather well at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B.

Comment: Unfortunately, your explicit assumption is incorrect.  The code running in the thread is pure C++, not Obj-C++, because it is shared code with the privileged daemon.

Comment: If the resultant program is a non Objective C daemon (i.e. the entire program is pure C), then it makes no sense to access "the `NSThread` it's running on", as there's no C concept of `NSThread` to call `cancel` on (though NSThread is just a wrapper for OS threads, and you can use normal thread signalling methods). If you mean that the same file is common between two resultant binaries, then just use preprocessors to remove the Objective C code when compiling as pure C, and leave it in when compiling to an Objective C target.

Comment: I mean that the same file is compiled into both binaries.  Even if I set up some macro hackery, won't an .mm file still turn into Obj-C++?  That's a definite no-no for a daemon.

Comment: Yes, so you'll need to configure your MakeFile to compile that one .mm as C++, or your XCode project settings to compile the specific .cpp file as Objective C++ in that one files instance. There's not really much of a way around this if you want a single file that builds as Objective C in one target, and pure C++ in another.

Comment: I was really hoping for something obscure through the posix thread interface, but I guess it was too much to hope for.